# Issue about javascript regex parsing rows and wrapping it

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to parse some html and modify it.

I have the following HTML:

```
When and how often am I online?
<br>
tuesday,thursday,saturday night
<br>
<br>
Taboos
<br>
i dont think i need it)....
<br>
<br>
If I´m momentarily not online, then...
<br>
I read a book
<br>
<br>
the best party, I ever attended
<br>
It was Italy
<br>
<br>
my favourite sport
<br>
I go to fitness
```

and I need to wrap by span tag only some rows:

```
<span>When and how often am I online?</span>
<br>
tuesday,thursday,saturday night
<br>
<br>
<span>Taboos</span>
<br>
i dont think i need it)....
<br>
<br>
<span>If I´m momentarily not online, then...</span>
<br>
I read a book
<br>
<br>
<span>the best party, I ever attended</span>
<br>
It was Italy
<br>
<br>
<span>my favourite sport</span>
<br>
I go to fitness
```

Other without changes
How can i do it? what regex can i use?

**UDPATE**

This is what I have tried, without any success:

```
description = description.replace(/<br><br>(.*)<br>/g,"<span>$1</span>");
```

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a free coding service (although it feels like it sometimes!) :)

Comment: please explain 'only some rows'.... Which kind of rows?

Comment: first row and rows after <br><br>

Comment: i have tried:   
description = description.replace(/<br><br>(.*)<br>/g,"<span>$1</span>"); but no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to rethink your strategy, because HTML manipulations using javascript like this are going to get ugly really fast. How can you be sure that the HTML is always going to have this exact setup?

If you still think you really need to do the replacement, I've created a [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y3AM5/1/).

The javascript splits the string at each line break and then loops through each value to check what needs to be done with it.

```
    var lines = yourHtmlString.split('\n');
    var arr = [];
    var lineCounter = 0;
    for(var i = 0;i<lines.length;i++) {
        if(lineCounter == 2 || i == 0) {
            arr.push('<span>' + lines[i] + '</span>');
            lineCounter = 0;
        }           
        else {
            arr.push(lines[i]);
        }

        if(lines[i] == '<br>') {
            lineCounter++;
        }
        else {
            lineCounter = 0;
        }
    }

    console.log(arr);
    console.log(arr.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regular expressions for this; just use simple logic and HTML processing that comes with the browser:

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = html;

var shouldWrap = true,
lineBreaks = 0;

[].forEach.call(container.childNodes, function(node) {
  if (node.nodeType == 3 && shouldWrap) {
    // okay, this is a little tricky =p
    var wrapper = document.createElement('span'),
    next = node.nextSibling;

    wrapper.appendChild(node);

    if (next) {
      container.insertBefore(wrapper, next);
    } else {
      container.appendChild(wrapper);
    }
    shouldWrap = false;
    lineBreaks = 0;
  } else if (node.nodeName = 'BR') {
    if (++lineBreaks >= 2) {
      shouldWrap = true;
    }
  }
});

console.log(container.innerHTML);
```